# Python - modify to optimal number of ticks on resize event

Tags: python, matplotlib

Matplotlib computes on first creation of a plot an optimal number of ticks and labels, so that the label strings do not overdraw another tick label. Is it possible to optimally modify this number of ticks on a resize event? If the figure size is increased then there may be an opportunity to have more ticks and labels. If the figure size is decreased then the number of ticks should be decreased whenever they overdraw other labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `resize_event` to change the number of ticks. This example uses `MaxNLocator` but you can use a different `Locator`. It makes the number of ticks grow as the width of the window grows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(np.random.rand(100), 'o')

def onresize(event):
    bbox = fig.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
    width, height = bbox.width * fig.dpi, bbox.height * fig.dpi
    tick_step = 100
    n = width / tick_step
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MaxNLocator(n))

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('resize_event', onresize)
plt.show()
```